# Windows 8 restore point behavior

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, restore

I've just installed Windows 8. I added all drivers needed, changed My Documents location (different partition). I also installed some most necessary applications. All in all, I have a system ready for work, very clean, without any junks. I'd like to be able to restore it in a few months, when it gets cluttered and slow.

Previously I used Clonezilla for that. Now I'm considering using Windows 8 restore points.

1. If I create a restore point now (manually) will it ever be deleted by system? (I know it deletes older restore points when it runs out of space, but does it do the same with manually created ones?)
2. If my system breaks down badly and won't start will I still be able to use the restore point?
3. Since now I'll install a lot of new software, which will write to the registry and create their files God only knows where in the system. Will system  restore remove **ALL** of that?
4. Will the system know after restore, that I changed My Documents directory?

Comment: Why vote down? o.0

Comment: Why don't you just update the Refresh image.  Which will allow you to restore you computer as is instead of the default Refresh image without your desktop applications.  As for the downvote this question encourages extended discussion by attempting to get the positives and negatives of something.

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question (all sub-questions are very specific now). Can you now please answer all of them?

Comment: I answered a similar question couple weeks ago: http://superuser.com/questions/599725/windows-8-custom-images/599747#599747 I can't predict the future.  I would not allow a restore point be my only backup.  I would simply duplicate the hdd using an image tool like Acronis or Clonezilla or create a custom `Refresh` image instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, I've learned this one through experience, it will delete it.
2. If by wont start, as in windows wont even start to boot, I don't know how it would be of use anyways, if you mean by access the recovery options in startup repair, as long as it's still there then yes.
3. As long as the restore point is made before the installs, yes it will remove them.
4. Yes.